# Accessibility for pickerview Voice Over

Tags: accessibility, uipickerview, voiceover

I need some help, I'm trying to finilize my first application and now I'm implementing the accessibility in orther the application can be used with VoiceOver.

The issu is I have 3 different pickerviews in one view controller but I cannot fix a label for each of them. The properties in the inspector identifier don't work for pickerView. If i use the method:

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, accessibilityLabelForComponent component: Int) -> String?

yes, I fix a label but it is the same for the three of them and I ineed each pickerView have its own label. Each pickerview have one component, but I don't know how to set up in other to differenciate each pickerView and have three different labels, one for each of them.

Any help is wellcome

Many thanks by anticipate

I include here the next:

1st.- a screenshot of one the pickerview selected and how its label in the inspector is setup, but it doesn't work at running:

[a screenshot of one the pickerview selected and how its label in the inspector is setup, but it doesn't work at running:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDPtW.png)

2.- the code used for any other control, label or text field which work for them but not for the pickerview:

```
extension Rithm {
func applyAccessibility() {
    logo.isAccessibilityElement = false
    kmMille.subviews[0].accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Milles", comment: "")
    kmMille.subviews[1].accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Kilometers", comment: "")
    switch kmMille.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 1:
        distanceTextField.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Please, enter a distance in Milles", comment: "")
    case 0:
        distanceTextField.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Please, enter a distance in Kilometers", comment: "")
    default:
        break

    }



    hourPickView.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Time selector, enter the hours used for the distance selected", comment: "") // DON'T WORK


}
```

}

3rd, the method used with the pickerview which work if you add one label and it is returned for all the pickerview in the view controller, however, I don't know how to fix here to add one label for each of them.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, accessibilityLabelForComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    hourPickView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Hour"
    secPickView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Sec"
    minPickView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Min"
    switch component {
    case 0:
        print("Este es: \(component)")
        if hourPickView.accessibilityIdentifier == "Hour" {
            switch pickerView.accessibilityIdentifier {
            case "Hour"?:
                return "Box for hour"
            case "Min"?:
                return "Box for minute"
            case "Sec"?:
                return "Box for second"
            default:
                return "Doesn't work"
            }


            //return "try to check what happens"
        } else {
            return "doesn't work"
        }
    default:
        print("\(component)")
        return "either"
    }

 }
```

As I told you all, thanks for your help!!!

Comment: format and post your code

Comment: Hi Daniel, I add information, code and photo, you can see better now.